Collecting / joining / waiting for parallel, depth-first ops in Dagster
After a much-appreciated assist from @zyd in this answer to parallel, deep-first execution in Dagster, I am now looking for a way to run an @op on the collected results of the graph run, or at least one that waits until they have all finished, since they don't have hard dependencies per se. My working code is as follows:
@op
def get_csv_filenames(context) -> List[str]:

@op(out=DynamicOut())
def generate_subtasks(context, csv_list:List[str]):
  for csv_filename in csv_list:
    yield DynamicOutput(csv_filename, mapping_key=csv_filename)

@op # no dep since 1st task
def load_csv_into_duckdb(context, csv_filename)

@op(ins={"start":In(Nothing)}
def transform_dates(context, csv_filename)

@op(ins={"start":In(Nothing)}
def from_code_2_categories(context, csv_filename)

@op(ins={"start":In(Nothing)}
def export_2_parquet(context, csv_filename)

@op(ins={"start":In(Nothing)}
def profile_dataset(context, csv_filename)

@graph
def process(context, csv_filename:str):
  task1 = load_csv_into_duckdb(context=context, csv_filename=csv_filename)
  task2 = transform_dates(start=task1, context=context, csv_filename=csv_filename)
  task3 = from_code_2_categories(start=task2, context=context, csv_filename=csv_filename)
  task4 = export_2_parquet(start=task3, context=context, csv_filename=csv_filename)
  profile_dataset(start=task4, context=context, csv_filename=csv_filename)

  
@job
def pipeline():
  csv_filename_list = get_csv_filenames()
  generate_subtasks(csv_filename_list).map(process)

I have tried the .map(process).collect() approach, but Dagster complains that Nonetype has no attribute collect. However, I've seen several examples online of this same approach and apparently it should work.
I have also tried for the @graph to return a list of the individual task return values, but DagsterUI complains that a graph-decorated function should return a dict with mapping keys. I could build that, but I feel I should instead pick that up from Dagster's execution context, which I don't know how to access from within the graph funct.
Does anyone have some pointers?

Can you show the things you've tried when returning an output from the graph? It feels like you need to return something from your last op, and the your graph probably needs to return that output. You'll also need to define a GraphOut in your graph definition, like @graph(out={"output": GraphOut()}) I'll rig up a toy example on my end and see if I can get something working

The 1st error I get from collect() is:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'collect'.
If I try to return a list of the individual return values of my individual tasks like return [task1, task2, task3, task4, ...], what I get is:
DagsterInvalidDefinitionError: @graph 'process' returned problematic value of type <class 'list'>. Expected return value from invoked node or dict mapping output name to return values from invoked nodes
This is why I think I could build such dict, but I think the kosher way is to get it from somewhere, maybe the context?

Don't try returning a list, just return from the graph  whatever the last op returns

Here's an example that worked for me:
from dagster import Definitions, op, DynamicOutput, graph, GraphOut, DynamicOut


@op
def a_op(path):
    return path

@op
def op2(path):
    return path

@op
def op3(path):
    return path

@op(out=DynamicOut(str))
def mapper():
    for i in range(10):
        yield DynamicOutput(str(i), mapping_key=str(i))

# I think what you were missing is returning the output from the graph here
@graph(out={"out": GraphOut()})
def nested(path: str):
    return op2(a_op(path))

@op
def consumer(context, paths: list[str]):
    context.log.info(paths)


@graph
def the_graph():
    consumer(mapper().map(nested).collect())

the_job = the_graph.to_job()

defs = Definitions(
    jobs=[the_job],
)


A graph is really just an organizational concept for grouping ops. At runtime nested graphs are flattened into a single graph for the whole job. This implies that if you want to use the output of an op in the nested graph, you need to return the output of the op from the nested graph. Then everything else works the same as any other op->op dependency.

A. WE. SOME. Thank you very much for your help! Pipeline is now running end-to-end successfully. 100/10 would ask again :D
